# AngularJS ng-class javascript animations doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, ng-animate, ng-class

I'm trying to attach js-defined animations to the ng-class directive via the usual syntax using add and remove but the animations won't run. Logging reveals that the add and remove functions don't get called.

```
app.animation( ".bob", function () {

    return {
        add : function ( element, done ) {
            // Do add animation here and call done when done.
        },
        remove : function ( element, done ) {
            // Do remove animation here and call done when done.
        }
    }
} );
```

This usually works fine with other directives like ngIf with it's enter and leave animations, but with ngClass it only seems to work with css-animations as proved by [the example in the documentation](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/docs/api/ng.directive%3angClass)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be using addClass and removeClass not add/remove. Also you need three parameters (element, className, done) you are missing the second.

Comment: addClass, removeClass, setClass, beforeAddClass, beforeRemoveClass, beforeSetClass.